# How do I input a performance curve in a vectorized Modelica chiller model (Dymola interface)?

Tags: vectorization, modelica, dymola

I am trying to vectorize a chiller model using the Modelica Buildings Library in Dymola (Modelica language). The chiller model is the Buildings.Fluid.Chillers.ElectricEIR model. The chiller model inputs and performance curves are identical, which allows them to be vectorized. When I check my model, I get an error repeated multiple times saying "Wrong number of indices in datChi[1]. There should be zero indices." (The error also occurs saying that there is an incorrect number of indices in datChi[2].)

Here is my current performance curve parameter definition:

```
parameter Path.ElectricEIRChiller_York_YK_Q3QQK3_5663kW_6_79COP_Vanes datChi;
```

Here is my current chiller definition:

```
>   Buildings.Fluid.Chillers.ElectricEIR Chi[numChi](
    redeclare package Medium1 = Medium,
    redeclare package Medium2 = Medium,
    show_T=true,
    per=datChi,
    energyDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial,
    dp1_nominal=dpCon_nominal,
    dp2_nominal=dpEva_nominal) "Vectorized chiller model"
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRSBE.png)

I have isolated the chiller into a model with only the chiller, sources, and sinks. The error still persists.
[model schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDPF3.png)

I have also tried to vectorize the performance curve as follows:

```
    parameter Path.ElectricEIRChiller_York_YK_Q3QQK3_5663kW_6_79COP_Vanes datChi;
```

which leads to errors when defining parameters associated with the performance curve. For example, where I originally had

```
mCon_flow_nominal = datChi.mCon_flow_nominal;
```

an error now occurs saying that the left hand side is a scalar and the right hand side is a vector (makes sense). However, I want to keep my nominal parameters as scalars.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add "each" next to the parameters defined in your chiller model:

```
> Buildings.Fluid.Chillers.ElectricEIR Chi[numChi](
    redeclare package Medium1 = Medium,
    redeclare package Medium2 = Medium,
    each show_T=true,
    each per=datChi,
    each energyDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial,
    each dp1_nominal=dpCon_nominal,
    each dp2_nominal=dpEva_nominal) "Vectorized chiller model";
```

This works if you have a vectorized component. If the component is not vectorized but you need multiple instances of a performance curve (like in Buildings.Applications.BaseClasses.Equipment.ElectricChillerParallel) you can use the command

```
fill(datChi, num)
```

where num is the number of performance curves needed.